# How to set number format to show all decimal digits in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, numbers, decimal, division

I have a problem in c++, I have this code to do a division:

```
long a = 33732193487;

int b = 1000000;

double c = (double)a/(double)b;
```

Well, I would like to store the complete result in the variable c, I mean:

```
c = 33732.193487;
```

for later, for example, use this value to make a sum or substrac. But I only get to store the result with one decimal.

Is there any option to store the 6 decimals with c++?

Thank you in advance! Sorry if my question is too obvious.

Comment: The number of _"decimals"_ isn't fixed with `double` values.

Comment: Do you want to store 6 decimals? Or as many as there are in the exact solution? You could write a `Rational` class, that stores the numerator and denominator. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Things get really strange when you realize you can't even accurately store the number `0.1` using type `double`. You should investigate floating point types theory in more details.

Comment: @verdery It depends on your implementation, mine has `sizeof(long) == 8` so `33732193487` will easily fit. You'd probably get a compiler warning if `long` was not large enough to store your number.

Comment: 2 ways, 1) store the double and output 6 decimals. 2) store the result times 1,000,000 as an integer and then divide by 1,000,000 to output.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess (a **complete** program would have been better): you're seeing six decimal places when you write the value to standard out:

```
std::cout << c << '\n';
```

Those six decimal places are the default **for output**; they have nothing to do with the precision of the **value** of `c`, which is determined by the **type** of `c`. For `double` you typically have about fifteen digits. To see those digits in your output statement, use `std::setprecision`:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << c << '\n';
```

But beware: you can use values greater than 15 in the call to `setprecision` and the stream inserter will happily generate more digits, with nonsensical values.